# Counting records using SQL and returning in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am trying to count the number of records I have in a certain. This is the SQL query I have been using and I have tried to echo $result, but nothing would print.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM barber_queue ");
echo $result;
```

I have also tried this code which managed to return something, however not in the format I would like

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM barber_queue ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
```

This returns:`Array ( [0] => 6 )`
While 6 is the correct amount of rows, I would just like the integer on its own as I want to use this amongst HTML to relay some information back to visitors.

Also this piece of code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM barber_queue ");
    print_r($result);
```

returns on the screen. :

```
mysqli_result Object ( )
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);// try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an alias "num" to the `COUNT()` keyword, the accessed the `$row` variable as an `array()`;

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) num FROM barber_queue ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['num'];
```

Comment: Perfect, worked wonders, but Im sure Ive seen somewhere that you can just print count directly from the result of the query?

Comment: No you can't. The query returns a resource. You need to fetch the result from that resource.

Comment: You can execute queries returning no result ... ex: `$mysqli->query("insert into table .....")` ... then you get the inserted id by calling extra function `mysql_insert_id` ... but if you want to get a rowset you have to fetch it first by calling  `mysqli_fetch_row($query)`

Answer (score 0):

you are missed `mysqli_fetch_row(...);`. you are dumping the system mysql_query object, which can not be access by `print_r` so you have this dump

Comment: Im sure I used fetch row in the middle example

Comment: of course, that's why you have result there ... if you want to count result rows `mysqli_num_rows` is the function you should use ... if you want to substitude the name of the field ... the clean SQl syntax is `field as newfieldname` - in your case `count(*) as count` for example ... but you need to fetch your result first. The `$mysqli->query` won't start fetching the result and because it is low level object it can not be dumpped successfuly by `print_r` or `var_dump`